# Ivy Ant task unable to resolve in eclipse workspace

Tags: eclipse, ant, ivy

I'm trying to use the ivy's [cachepath](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/cachepath.html) Ant task to retrieve an eclipse's project classpath in order to use it to do a GWT compilation.

I use IvyDE in eclipse and followed IvyDE's [Eclipse's Ant integration guide](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/history/latest-milestone/ant.html)

so far so good: i can run ivy's ant task in eclipse's Ant builds

The problem I'm facing is that ivy's [cachepath](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/cachepath.html) is **unable to resolve dependencies to other eclipse projects**

My Ant's build.xml is like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="GWT Ant Build" basedir="." default="gwt-compile"
         xmlns:a4e="antlib:org.ant4eclipse"
         xmlns:ac="antlib:net.sf.antcontrib"
         xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <ivy:settings file="ivysettings.xml" />
    <ivy:resolve file="../ivy.xml" />
    <ivy:cachepath pathid="ivy.deps.default" conf="default" />

    <pathconvert property="classpathProp" refid="ivy.deps.default"/>
    <echo>:::: ${classpathProp}</echo>
    ....
</project>
```

The ivysettings.xml simply re-defines the local and cache dirs:

```xml
<ivysettings>
    <property name="ivy.local.default.root" 
              value="/home/ivy/local" override="false"/>
    <caches defaultCacheDir="/home/ivy/cache"/>
    <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings.xml"/>
</ivysettings>
```

If the project do **NOT** have dependencies to other eclipse projects, everything works fine, **BUT** if the eclipse project depends upon another eclipse project ivy's [cachepath](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/cachepath.html) is unable to resolve the dependant project:

```
[ivy:resolve] :: problems summary ::
[ivy:resolve] :::: WARNINGS
[ivy:resolve]       module not found: r01#r01fbClasses;latest.integration
[ivy:resolve]   ==== local: tried
[ivy:resolve]     /home/ivy/local/r01/r01fbClasses/[revision]/ivys/ivy.xml
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact r01#r01fbClasses;latest.integration!r01fbClasses.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     /home/ivy/local/r01/r01fbClasses/[revision]/jars/r01fbClasses.jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== shared: tried
                             ...
[ivy:resolve]   ==== public: tried
[ivy:resolve]            ...
```

NOTE that using IvyDE everything is OK, the problem is ONLY with Ivy's Ant tasks

I don't know if eclipse workspace resolving is possible using Ant tasks...

Comment: ivy is used to manage the dependencies of a project. Why would you use an ivy file located in another project? Creates tight coupling between projects which is always a bad idea. Personally I publish projects builds into Nexus and then use this to share dependencies between my projects.

Comment: I'm still developing my artifacts inside eclipse using ivyDE; it's a great tool to manage the dependencies, before they're published

My problem is that I've some NOT published ivy (ivyDE) managed projects  and an ANT task to build a GWT project that depends on these not published eclipse projects; you're right if the dependant projects where published everything would be easier

Comment: I would suggest setting up a Nexus repository. Very easy and very useful for managing dependencies internal and 3rd party. Another less generic option is to use the "publish" task to store build artefacts locally under the "$HOME/.ivy2/shared" area. The latter is not terribly well documented, which is why I favour setting up Nexus.